# How to assign domain user to MS SQL Server instance with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have spine up an Azure Virtual Machine using following command:

```
az group create --location $location --name $resourceGroup
az vm create -n $virtualMachine -g $resourceGroup --image MicrosoftSQLServer:SQL2017-WS2016:Standard:14.0.1000200 --location $location --admin-username $admin --admin-password $password --verbose --vnet-name Desap-VNET --subnet Subnet2
az vm open-port --port 3389 -g $resourceGroup -n $virtualMachine
```

and connect via remote desktop, and configured the machine so that it is joint to Azure Active Directory. Now my task is to connect an AD user to Sql server, which I have done it manually, How could I automate this task using power shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect an AD user to SQl server using the below documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure